# Get ComboBox Selected Item content name in c# in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, combobox, mvvm-light

I am using a ComboBox named "Combo" and have binded its items using MVVMLight.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Combo" Header="From" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrencyList}"/>
```

in the XMAL page:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Currency}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

I want to get the selected item name from the combo box. I tried,

```
string SelectionText = ((ComboBoxItem)Combo.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

But, it is not working.

Comment: what is the error/output of it ?

Comment: You might want to consider accepting the answer here and one of the answer that worked for you in your other question if your expecting to get any further help.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a sample to display the `SelectedItem` from the `ComboBox`.

```
ResultTextBlock.Text = ((ComboBoxItem)ComboBoxMenu.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

So like wise to get the property `name`, try `.Name` instead of `.Content`.

Reference: [ComboBox in Windows Phone 8.1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2d2d83/combobox-in-windows-phone-8-1/)

Comment: @AbdurRahim If it does help your question please do vote it, or if it answers your question mark it as an answer so it might help the others too!